# Ubuntu With WordPress Pre-Installed

Tags: wordpress

I know Ubuntu does not officially have any .iso files like this, but has anyone made a custom image of Ubuntu that has Wordpress installed from the get-go?

Comment: In my opinion it is better to have a bash script to update and install new software after a clean installation. This way you have more control over what's happening.

Comment: @KevInski - that is very true, and in the long run I will go that route, but for the quick and dirty solution I was just looking to see if there were any custom made images that have Wordpress included.  Do you have a bash script that does this?

Comment: Sorry I don't have a script for that, but the installation seems trivial. There are tons of tutorials. For the DB stuff you could use the top-rated answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33470753/create-mysql-database-and-user-in-bash-script)

Comment: @user2676140 seems like a waste of time to make. the use-case will be extremely narrow and at the same time setting up wordpress in ubuntu is mere minutes.